# Select all produtcts from the first category

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all products from the first category of the table, the problem is that I don't know the categories names

```
id  category  product
1   cat_1     prod_1
2   cat_2     prod_2
3   cat_2     prod_3
4   cat_3     prod_4
5   cat_1     prod_5
```

what I need is:

```
id  category  product
1   cat_1     prod_1
5   cat_1     prod_5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using an order list you could use a subselect limt 1 for get the category value

```
    select * from my_table 
    where category = (
    select category
    from my_table 
    order by id limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query, it will get list of products from first category(based on table record index):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE category  = (SELECT category FROM `tbl_name` limit 0, 1)
```